# Animating title change in ExpansionTile

Tags: flutter

I have an ExpansionTile that have different titles in expanded\collapsed state.

```
class _ExpandablePaneState extends State<ExpandablePane>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool isExpanded = false;
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _iconTurns;
  static final Animatable<double> _easeInTween =
      CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeIn);
  static final Animatable<double> _halfTween =
      Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 0.5);
  Duration _kExpand = Duration(milliseconds: 250);
  Widget _myAnimatedWidget;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(duration: _kExpand, vsync: this);
    _iconTurns = _controller.drive(_halfTween.chain(_easeInTween));
    _controller.value = 0.0;
    _myAnimatedWidget = widget.collapsedTitle;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.transparent),
      child: ExpansionTile(
        onExpansionChanged: (value) {
          if (value) {
            _controller.forward();
          } else {
            _controller.reverse();
          }
          setState(() {
            isExpanded = value;
            _myAnimatedWidget =
                isExpanded ? widget.expandedTitle : widget.collapsedTitle;
          });
        },
        title: Expanded(
          child: Stack(children: [
            AnimatedSwitcher(
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2500),
              transitionBuilder: (child, animation) => ScaleTransition(
                child: child,
                scale: animation,
              ),
              child: _myAnimatedWidget,
            ),
            Positioned.fill(
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: RotationTransition(
                  turns: _iconTurns,
                  child: const Icon(Icons.expand_more),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ]),
        ),
        children: widget.content,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to make an animation between these states, how I can achieve it?
I tried AnimatedSwitcher, but it didn't work. I'm totally don't see an animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below
You can wrap `_myAnimatedWidget` with `Container` and provide `key: ValueKey<bool>(isExpanded)` 
From official example https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html

```
This key causes the AnimatedSwitcher to interpret this as a "new"
child each time the count changes, so that it will begin its animation
when the count changes.
```

I also remove `Expanded` in `title` 
code snippet

```
child: Container(
            key: ValueKey<bool>(isExpanded), child: _myAnimatedWidget),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExpandablePane extends StatefulWidget {
  Widget expandedTitle;
  Widget collapsedTitle;
  List<Widget> content;

  ExpandablePane({this.expandedTitle, this.collapsedTitle, this.content});

  @override
  _ExpandablePaneState createState() => _ExpandablePaneState();
}

class _ExpandablePaneState extends State<ExpandablePane>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool isExpanded = false;
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _iconTurns;
  static final Animatable<double> _easeInTween =
      CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeIn);
  static final Animatable<double> _halfTween =
      Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 0.5);
  Duration _kExpand = Duration(milliseconds: 250);
  Widget _myAnimatedWidget;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(duration: _kExpand, vsync: this);
    _iconTurns = _controller.drive(_halfTween.chain(_easeInTween));
    _controller.value = 0.0;
    _myAnimatedWidget = widget.collapsedTitle;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.transparent),
      child: ExpansionTile(
        onExpansionChanged: (value) {
          if (value) {
            _controller.forward();
          } else {
            _controller.reverse();
          }
          setState(() {
            isExpanded = value;
            _myAnimatedWidget =
                isExpanded ? widget.expandedTitle : widget.collapsedTitle;
          });
        },
        title: Stack(children: [
          AnimatedSwitcher(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2500),
            transitionBuilder: (child, animation) => ScaleTransition(
              child: child,
              scale: animation,
            ),
            child: Container(
                key: ValueKey<bool>(isExpanded), child: _myAnimatedWidget),
          ),
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: RotationTransition(
                turns: _iconTurns,
                child: const Icon(Icons.expand_more),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ]),
        children: widget.content,
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            ExpandablePane(
              expandedTitle: Text("expand"),
              collapsedTitle: Text("collapsed"),
              content: [Text("1"), Text("2"), Text("3")],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try

Comment: Glad to help. please upvote or mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks.